# @import not showing Fontawesome icons in CSS-in-JS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, emotion, css-in-js

This was how I was importing Fontawesome icons:

**src/App.css**

```
@import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";`
```

When I moved that `@import` to CSS-in-Js ([emotion](https://emotion.sh/)):

**src/App.js**

```
// JS:
const imports = css`
  @import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";`
`

// JSX:
<Global styles={imports} />
```

The Fontawesome icons stopped displaying.

I had to be more explicit with the Node module's path for the Fontawesome icons to show again:

```
const imports = css`
  @import '../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
`
```

Is it because the second `@` only works in CSS? Or there's another reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@import` rule in css must be defined at the top of the stylesheet before any other at-rule (except `@charset` and `@layer`) and style declarations, or it will be [ignored](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import).

When you moved the `@import` to *CSS-in-JS*, the path `@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css` was not being resolved correctly. You had to provide the relative path from the current file to the *Fontawesome* css in your `node_modules` directory. This is because *CSS-in-JS* do not have the same ability to resolve module paths as traditional css preprocessors or bundlers.

```
import { css } from '@emotion/react';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';

const styles = css`
 /* Your styles here */
`;

// Then in your component
<div css={styles}>Your content</div>
```